# Can CruiseControl.NET be configured to have pre-build options set from a web page?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'd like to create some tasks that will be triggered manually. These would include various installers being generated. I'd like to be able to set some options that will be passed to the installer build task before I manually trigger the build.

Can ccnet be configured in such a way as to allow me to do this? Preferably I'd just have a page that has a bunch of check boxes indicating to include this piece in the created installer. I can handle the installer part, I'm just looking for information on the ccnet side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes parameters: http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Parameters

When you manually trigger the build a dialog pops up with controls to configure the parameters.